# View PDF files on a Web page without downloading?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, open-source

Have a bunch of pdf files I want to display on a web page (like google books). I do not want them to be possible to download, or at least hinder it.

Are there any open soruce solutions? HTML5, Javascript?

Comment: http://slideshare.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

or:

http://trapeze.xyrka.com/

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that its working good in Chrome and Firefox but not so well in Internet Explorer and Safari. Have not tried Opera.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [pdf viewer in javascript and html called pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). However, in order for the pdf to get to the browser, it will still need to be downloaded.

There is no way to display something in a browser without downloading it. It may take a bit of work to find the original asset (looking through the network tab in chrome dev tools) but the original pdf will still be downloaded.